# compare 2 iterators by address

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I defined the vector:

```
std::vector<int> Numbers;
```

In addition, I defined an iterator and I initialized it to the beginning of the vector:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator numIt=Numbers.begin();
```

I use that iterator for passing on the vector by for-loop:

```
for(; numIt!=Numbers.end(); ++numIt) {
    if(func(Numbers,numIt)==true){
       return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

...where `func` is the following function:

```
bool func(std::vector<int> Numbers.end, std::vector<int>::iterator curElement){
  std::vector<int>::iterator nextElement=curElement;
  ++nextElement;
  if(nextElement== Numbers.end()){
    return false;
  }
  int ICurElement=*curElement;
  int InextElement=*nextElement;
  return ICurElement>InextElement ? true : false;
}
```

**Why do I never get into the `if` in `func`?**.

the full code

```
bool CurGreaterNext(std::vector<int>& set,std::vector<int>::iterator& curElement ,int size){
std::vector<int>::iterator nextElement=curElement;
  if(size == 1){
    return false;
  }
  ++nextElement;
  if(nextElement==set.end()){
    std::cout<< " im hereee "<<std::endl;
  }

  int ICurElement=*curElement;
  int InextElement=*nextElement;
  return ICurElement>InextElement ? true : false;
}

template<class TheSet , class Predicate >
void funkiFun(TheSet set , Predicate func){
  typename TheSet::iterator end=set.end();
  int count=0;
  for(typename TheSet::iterator it = set.begin(); it != end ; it++){
    if(func(set,it,set.size()-count)==true){
      std::cout << "Wo-Ho the number is "<< *it << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    count++;
  }
  std::cout <<  std::endl;
};
```

The main

```
 int main{
    int a1 = 1;
      int a2 = 2;
      int a3 = 3;
      int a4 = 4;
      int a5 = 5;
    std::vector<int> Numbers;
    Numbers.push_back(a1 );
      Numbers.push_back(a2 );
      Numbers.push_back(a3 );
      Numbers.push_back(a4 );
     Numbers.push_back(a5 );
    funkiFun<std::vector<int> >(numbers5,CurGreaterNext);
    }
```

Comment: for(; numIt!=set.end();++ numIt) in this line what is set? Please post your full code

Comment: Because you are passing the vector by copy, so the end iterator of the parameter will never match against an iterator of the original vector (your `curElement`, or `nextElement`). You want to pass `set` by const-reference, e.g. `auto func(std::vector<int> const& set, std::vector<int>::iterator curElement) { ... }`).

Comment: Your vector is empty, so `begin() == end()` and you never enter the loop.

Comment: @Holt ,I thought that is the problem but  I read in  website (cpprefrence) that the iterator at c++ is pointing to the elemnt, it doesn't mean that iteator is a pointer?

Comment: @Quentin i checked the func with the vector<int>={1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: @Bizzu The problem is not the iterator but the container - When you call `func`, you are making a copy of `Numbers` into `set`, so inside `func`, `set` is a different object from `Numbers`, so an iterator from `Numbers` will never match an iterator from `set`.

Comment: `bool func(std::vector<int> Numbers.end, std...` That `.end` is very suspicious. Delete it and try again.

Comment: @Holt i think you right, i will check it , thank you

Comment: @Holt so that is not the problem, and it more strange from my thought, i try to change the condition to "begin" insted of "end" and it work, so i think there is a problem with the itearator

Comment: Your are not showing your real code, as @Ripi2 already stated, so no one can help you.

Comment: @manni66 i add the full code..

Comment: _Why do I never get into the if in func?._ Which if in what function? TheSet is still a copy.

Comment: @manni66 its copy but i send the copy by refrence, so i will get the same Set, am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering this just to **show a way of debugging**. I hope you learn it.

I made a few modifications so your code would compile. Also I added some "std::cout" to see whats happenig (the simplest debug tool you can use).

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool CurGreaterNext(std::vector<int>& set,std::vector<int>::iterator& curElement ,int size){
std::vector<int>::iterator nextElement=curElement;
  std::cout <<"CurGreaterNext() with size= " <<size <<" (set.size()= " <<set.size() <<") nextElement *it= " <<*nextElement <<"\n";
  if(size == 1){
    std::cout <<"in CurGreaterNext() and size=1\n";
    return false;
  }
  ++nextElement;
  if(nextElement==set.end()){
    std::cout<< " im hereee "<<std::endl;
  }
  int ICurElement=*curElement;
  int InextElement=*nextElement;
  std::cout <<"ICurElement= " << ICurElement <<"  InextElement= " << InextElement <<"\n";
  return ICurElement>InextElement ? true : false;
};

template<class TheSet , class Predicate >
void funkiFun(TheSet set , Predicate func){
  typename TheSet::iterator end=set.end();
  int count=0;
  std::cout <<"at funkiFun\n";
  for(typename TheSet::iterator it = set.begin(); it != end ; it++){
    std::cout << "inside loop with count= " << count <<"\n";
    if(func(set,it,set.size()-count)==true){
      std::cout << "Wo-Ho the number is "<< *it << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    count++;
  }
  std::cout <<  std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int a1 = 1;
      int a2 = 2;
      int a3 = 3;
      int a4 = 4;
      int a5 = 5;
    std::vector<int> Numbers;
    Numbers.push_back(a1 );
      Numbers.push_back(a2 );
      Numbers.push_back(a3 );
      Numbers.push_back(a4 );
     Numbers.push_back(a5 );
    funkiFun<std::vector<int>>(Numbers,CurGreaterNext);
    }
```

And this is the output:

> ```
> at funkiFun
> inside loop with count= 0
> CurGreaterNext() with size= 5 (set.size()= 5) nextElement *it= 1
> ICurElement= 1  InextElement= 2
> inside loop with count= 1
> CurGreaterNext() with size= 4 (set.size()= 5) nextElement *it= 2
> ICurElement= 2  InextElement= 3
> inside loop with count= 2
> CurGreaterNext() with size= 3 (set.size()= 5) nextElement *it= 3
> ICurElement= 3  InextElement= 4
> inside loop with count= 3
> CurGreaterNext() with size= 2 (set.size()= 5) nextElement *it= 4
> ICurElement= 4  InextElement= 5
> inside loop with count= 4
> CurGreaterNext() with size= 1 (set.size()= 5) nextElement *it= 5
> in CurGreaterNext() and size=1
> ```

As you see, your `if(nextElement==set.end())` is never called because the previous comparison `if(size == 1)` returns before.

Comment: i removed the size condition, and it still didnt work

Comment: If I delete (or comment) the `return false` inside `if(size == 1)` block it does print "im hereee". Compare your code with mine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your code is incrementing count in the outer loop, and subtracting it from size(), passing that into your function.  When you are on the last item, size (in your predicate) is 1, and it returns before it ever reaches the code you expect to reach.

Why are you doing this strangeness with size and count in the first place?

Code suggestions:
remove count, size(), and the argument from your predicate.
use auto instead of declaring iterators from the vector
simplify your code:

```
int ICurElement=*curElement;
int InextElement=*nextElement;
return ICurElement>InextElement ? true : false;
```

could be:

```
return *curElement > *nextElement;
```

In your predicate, after testing if nextElement is end, if it is you cannot dereference it later in the function.  Perhaps that should be the case for returning false instead of using that "size" argument, which is just weird.

Comment: The reason is to solve the problem in another way, after i saw that condition don't help for my example i removed it and it still didnt work

Answer (score -1):

```
for (; numIt != set.end(); ++numIt) {
    if (func(Numbers, numIt) == true) {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

In the for loop you are asigning (`=`) `numIt` to the `Numbers::end()`, not comparing (`==`).

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no assignment operator used in the code snippet you are showing

Comment: Ohhh my bad. Saw it now, the exclamation. Sorry